# multiple level complex model creates many connection when executing linq query

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a complex/deep model such as:

```
public class model1 {
    public virtual model2 Model2 {get;set;}
}

public class model2 {

    public virtual model3 Model3 {get;set;}
}

public class model3 {
    public virtual string prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

my linq query:

```
var db = new dbcontext();

var results = (from I in db.Model1
               where i.Model2.Model3.prop1=="somevalue"
               select I).toList();
```

when  the query is executed in a 1 cpu DB server it uses the same connection/process/session

when the query is executed in a 4 cpu db server it creates several process but shows that is shares the same sessionID.

Is this a natural behavior in  sql server or is EF doing something I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a natural behavior in sql server ?

Yes, it is directly linked to the [max degree of parallelism Option](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181007%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of SqlServer

> or is EF doing something I don't know about?

As far as I know EF is not able to perform parallelism on the same query or connection